# PowerShell removes variables from concatenation

Tags: powershell

I want to iterate over folders and execute a command per folder, ignoring the already processed ones.

For this I'm trying to concatenate variables to produce a command and then execute this string.
But PowerShell (v7.2.5) is removing the variables from concatenation (or replacing them with empty strings).
I tried many different syntaxes like `$($var1) + $($var2)` or `"$var1  $var2"`, none of them work. My current approach (it will run with `Invoke-Expression -Command` instead of `echo`):

```
$arguments = "-a -b -c"
$exe = "C:\foo\bar.exe"
$targetdir = "C:\path\"

Get-ChildItem $targetdir -Directory | ForEach-Object -Parallel {If($_.FullName.Contains("processed")){continue}; echo ("{0} -d {1} {2}" -f $($exe),$($_.FullName),$($arguments));} -ThrottleLimit 8
```

Expected:

```
C:\foo\bar.exe -d C:\path\101 -a -b -c
C:\foo\bar.exe -d C:\path\102 -a -b -c
C:\foo\bar.exe -d C:\path\103 -a -b -c
```

Output:

```
 -d C:\path\101
 -d C:\path\102
 -d C:\path\103
```

Why is PowerShell removing paths or arguments from the concatenation and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As stated in the the [`ForEach-Object` MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object?view=powershell-7.2#notes):

> The `ForEach-Object -Parallel` parameter set runs script blocks in parallel on separate process threads. The `$using:` keyword allows passing variable references from the cmdlet invocation thread to each running script block thread.

[**Do not use continue outside of a loop, switch, or trap**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2#do-not-use-continue-outside-of-a-loop-switch-or-trap):

> Using `continue` inside a pipeline, such as a `ForEach-Object` script block, not only exits the pipeline, it potentially terminates the entire runspace.

You can use [`return`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_return?view=powershell-7.2) to emulate the behavior that [`continue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_continue?view=powershell-7.2) has on a loop:

```
$arguments = '-a -b -c'
$exe = 'C:\foo\bar.exe'
$targetdir = 'C:\path'

Get-ChildItem $targetdir -Directory | ForEach-Object -Parallel {
    if($_.FullName.Contains('processed')) {
        return
    }
    "{0} -d {1} {2}" -f $using:exe, $_.FullName, $using:arguments
} -ThrottleLimit 8
```

Comment: Nicely done. Note that the wording in the docs is a bit misleading: "passing variable _references_" should be "passing variable _values_".

Comment: @mklement0 do you think it's misleading ? I think "the variable being a reference of the object" is accurate for runspaces (not for other contexts where `$using:` is used, such as Remoting)

Comment: Yes, because two unrelated concepts are being conflated: PowerShell _variables_ and their _values_:  A value is an instance of a .NET type, which may or may not be a _reference_ - not to a _variable_ but to an instance of a _reference type_. If a PowerShell variable's value happens to be an instance of a _value type_, a _copy_ of it is passed to the other runspace, and no references of any kind are involved.

Comment: To put it differently: `$using:var` is a placeholder for the _value_ of PowerShell variable `$var` (irrespective of whether that value is a .NET reference or value type), not for the variable itself. It is for that reason that you cannot _assign_ to `$using:` expressions.

Comment: @mklement0 right I see what you mean, got to read it a few times :P but isn't the __value of the variable__ a reference to the original object ? We know we can update the original object from within the context of the runspace so: `$object = @('hello'); $null | ForEach-Object -Parallel { $object = $using:object; $object[0] = 'world' }; $object`

Comment: it is only a _reference_ if the value happens to be an instance of a _.NET reference type_. If the value is an instance of a _.NET value type_, say, `[int]` or `[datetime]`, a _copy_ is passed. This behavior is fundamental to .NET and applies to any context where objects are passed (as distinct from language-specific features that allow passing value-_containers_ (variables) by reference, such as `ref` in C#).

Comment: In other words: if the value of `$var` _happens to_ contain an instance of a reference type, then `$using:var` passes a _reference_ to that instance, so that both the original and the parallel
runspace (thread) see the very same object. This indeed allows for potential _modification_ of the object in the parallel runspace, but you need to manage concurrent access explicitly to ensure thread safety.
If you wanted to do the same for a variable value that is an instance of a _value type_, you would have to wrap it in an instance of a reference type, as in your `$object = @('hello')` example.